# how to fetch data from postgresql using d3.js

Tags: python, postgresql, d3.js, psycopg2

Previously I am using **CSV** to store data and by that, I am making the graphs.
But now I want to know how to get data from **PostgreSQL** using **d3.js**.

If anyone knows please help me I am totally new user to PostgreSQL.

```
import psycopg2
import sys
from  flask import Flask,render_template
import os

os.chmod("/home/dell/Charts/static/data/data.csv", 0o777)
con = None
con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='mydb' user='postgres' password='Password'")  
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("""COPY data_lc TO '/home/dell/Charts/static/data/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;""")

cur.close()
```

**This Code working Properly**

But I want to know is there any way to get the data directly from the **PostgreSQL** by the **D3.js**

**html code**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>LineChart</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="linechart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="static/js/Linechart.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would motivate the community if you could post some code samples of what you have tried already. A few pointers: Since you use Flask I would recommend taking a look at  [PsycoPG2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) to interface with PostgreSQL. Next you need to create a route in Flask which fetches the data and returns it as JSON for D3.js to consume.

Comment: @Timusan If possible can you tell me how to do that.
But my database size is huge so I can't make any file for that.

Comment: As pointed out, SO is not a tutorial site but a Q&A for programming problems. You are not displaying a problem here, you are simply asking for a tutorial. Please try to find a solution by yourself and if then stuck on an actual programming issue ask away. It is about showing effort to solve things yourself first. A few more pointers to help you on your way: Iterate over the records in your PostgreSQL cursor, create the proper data structure while doing so, convert to and return JSON to the client via Flask: [Returning JSON from Flask](/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view).

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a view in flask that queries the database and returns the results as a json

```
import psycopg2
import sys
from  flask import Flask,render_template
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/data')
def send_data():
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='mydb' user='postgres' password='Password'")  
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""select * from  data_lc""")
    data = [col for col in cur]
    cur.close()
    return jsonify(data)
```

then with d3 you can call the url with

```
d3.json("https://your_flas_kapp.com/data").then(...)
```